# Linked Server Error: Unable to read excel 2010 data through sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, excel, import

I am trying to read the data from the excel file through the SQL Server 2008.

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
      'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\Hierarchy.xlsx',
      'SELECT * FROM [Group$]')
```

Its giving me a weird error:

```
OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Unspecified error".
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)".
```

Excel sheet format is correct, path is correct.
don't know why its giving me an error.

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution:

I save the existing file in backward compatibility and then fire this one:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
'Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;Database=D:\Hierarchy.xls;', 
[Group$])
```

Don't know why it works and others not, may someone have a good idea about this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ACE OleDB and excel version 12.0

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM 
OPENROWSET
(           

        'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
        'Data Source=C:\Hierarchy.xlsx;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0;HDR=YES"', 
        'SELECT * FROM [Group$]'
)
```

Comment: Gives following error: OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Could not find installable ISAM.".
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".

Comment: Try installing the ACE provider from this [URL](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

Comment: Note that this answer is a good one if you're Excel version is 2007 or later. If it's 2003 or earlier than you want to use the Jet connection, as in your original post.

Comment: The installable ISAM error is because it should be `Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"'`

Comment: It is excel 2010 version.